# how to get a sequence after a word with whitespace

Tags: python, string, parsing, bioinformatics, genbank

For school I have to parse a string after a word with a lot of whitespace, but I just can't get it.
Because the file is a genbank.

So for example:

```
BLA                                                                                                             
      1 sjafhkashfjhsjfhkjsfkjakshfkjsjkf
      2 isfshkdfhjksfkhksfhjkshkfhkjsakjfhk
      3 kahsfkjshakjfhksjhfkskjfkaskfksj

//
```

What I have tried is this.

```
if line.startswith("BLA"):

       start = line.find("BLA")
       end = line.find("//")
       line = line[:end]
       s_string = ""
       string = list()
       if s_string:
           string.append(line)


        else:
            line = line.strip()
            my_seq += line
```

But what I get is:

```
**output**
BLA
```

and that is the only thing it get and I want to get the output be like

```
**output**
BLA 1 sjafhkashfjhsjfhkjsfkjakshfkjsjkf
    2 isfshkdfhjksfkhksfhjkshkfhkjsakjfhk
    3 kahsfkjshakjfhksjhfkskjfkaskfksj
```

So I don't know what to do, I tried to get it like that last output. But without success. My teacher told me that I had to do like. If BLA is True you can go iterate it. And if you see "//" you have to stop, but when I tried it with that True - statement I get nothing.

I tried to search it up online, and it said I had to do it with bio seqIO. But the teacher said we can't use that.

Comment: Your code is not complete since `my_seq` was not defined. Moreover you define `s_string=""` just before a `if s_string` condition. So this condition will never be `True`

Comment: You may look at this link to know [how to post a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)

Comment: Sorry i copied my real code and changed a little bit. But forget to change my_seq

Comment: Thank you. ^^ I think it is better for me to just ask a classmate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
lines = """BLA
  1 sjafhkashfjhsjfhkjsfkjakshfkjsjkf
  2 isfshkdfhjksfkhksfhjkshkfhkjsakjfhk
  3 kahsfkjshakjfhksjhfkskjfkaskfksj

//"""

lines = lines.strip().split("//")
lines = lines[0].split("BLA")
lines = [i.strip() for i in lines]
print("BLA", " ", lines[1])
```

> **Output:**

```
BLA   1 sjafhkashfjhsjfhkjsfkjakshfkjsjkf
      2 isfshkdfhjksfkhksfhjkshkfhkjsakjfhk
      3 kahsfkjshakjfhksjhfkskjfkaskfksj
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I did it kinda different but  seeing this helped me to understand it more. So thank you very much!!!!